# Qt3 on Windows?

Tags: qt, porting, qt3

I need to port one of my old program to Windows. The current version uses Qt 3 on Linux.
I'd like to see it within few days only to do some tests.

Instead of porting my code on Qt 4 (no time now), is it possible to recompile on Windows with Qt 3? Do I also need minGW? Which problems may I have doing this porting?

I can't find Qt 3 for windows, can someone give me a link? or I can use the same qt source I use on Linux?

Comment: Qt3 was not available for free on Windows. You had to purchase a licence back then, I don't know if it has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT4 still has back-compatible QT3 classes, prefixed with Q3* (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt3support.html)

You should be able to compile & run you QT3 app on QT4 via those classes with minimal adaptations.

Comment: I've tried to compile Qt3 on Windows with no success. Then I tried Qt4 with back-compatible Qt3 classes... and I discover I used a some other Unix libraries such as Xlib...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can !

Download the [qt-win-3.3.x-8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtwin/files/Unofficial%20Qtwin/qt-win-3.3.x-8/qt-3.3.x-p8.7z/download) project on Sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

Qt-3.2 for Windows was also distributed in a CD bundled with the book "C++ GUI programming with Qt3" at no additional cost with a license for non-commercial use.

ISBN: 978-0131240728

The supported compilers were MSVC and Borland. MingW is not mentioned.

Comment: It's still listed on amazon and costs less than 1 USD (+shipping) as a used item. Hard to be sure that the CD is still inside before buying, though.